# How to run php extensions at runtime

Tags: php

I'm trying to load a php extension at runtime. As the use of dl() is discouraged and it is removed from PHP i'm using php extension directives but it doesn't work either.

```
ini_set('extension','php_gmp.dll');

if(extension_loaded( 'gmp' ))
    echo 'GMP is Loaded';
```

Is it possible to do it ?

The reason why i want to do it is that my application needs gmp and want to load gmp even if gmp is not running on the web server.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to use an extension and it's not loaded, then your application has nothing to do with it. Your environment simply don't fit your app requirements, so best choice here is to show that and end execution

Comment: i don't think you can load extensions from within a script, it must be set in the php.ini, then the webserver needs to be restarted to reflect the changes.

Comment: @AlmaDo No, That's not the case. without GMP my app works great as well but i wanted to run it at runtime.

Comment: How does it work if you "need to load GMP to make it working?"

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 I read about extension directives but doesn't work either.

Comment: @AlmaDo it nedds GMP but not depends on it. just some part of the app needs gmp but i check if gmp is loaded or not. If not i handle it another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function named `dl` which is supported till PHP `5.3`. Note that this function was removed from most SAPIs in `PHP 5.3` and was removed from `PHP-FPM` in `PHP 7.0.0`.

dl `Loads a PHP extension at runtime`

> - dl() is not supported when PHP is built with ZTS support.
> - dl() is case sensitive on Unix platforms.
> - This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

There is also a php variable that can be set in `ini` file which needs access to the configurations.
    extension Which dynamically loadable extensions to load when PHP starts up.

> One option is to PEAR package your code and add dependencies on the
>   required extensions. Then the code will warn you or refuse to install
>   if the extensions are missing.

***Note**: Don't search for any `ini_set` related methods as it has never supported loading extensions at runtime.

The best practice and the only way to achieve what you want is to provide the environment for your php script
   first.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to load extensions via [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). The [`extension`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) directive is only changable in *php.ini* as described in the [Path and Directories](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.path-directory) section.

Comment: It seems that there is no option here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`dl()` is the only -theoretical- way to achieve that, `ini_set()` will not work as the `extension` directives will only get processed at PHP's startup. However loading extensions at runtime can be considered bad practice as this could be used to circumvent administrative restrictions.

Also it is only a theoretical option, as most shared web-hosters will disable the function `dl()`, and it [will not being available at all in PHP>5.3 and the most SAPIs because of some stability issues)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)

The only way to enable GMP support is to purchase a web hosting plan where you are `root` and can install the software you wish but probably you can also live with [`BC math`](http://php.net/manual/de/book.bc.php)?

Comment: [`dl()`](http://us1.php.net/dl) isn't an option since in PHP>=5.3 it was removed from SAPI (thus, I'm not sure if it worth to be mentioned)

Comment: Yes i agree with you. It turns out that the only way is to run it from within the web server settings. and dl() has been removed as of 5.3

Comment: imo, worth to be mentioned: "yes" as it is not deprecated but *only broken* in some SAPIs, but I explained a little more that it is just a theoretical option.

Comment: It seems that there is no option here. Thanks all

Comment: @User1234 Probably you can live with bc math?  http://php.net/manual/de/book.bc.php

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes but i think GMP is better and also bc Math might be disabled as well

Comment: It is likely that `BC math` is installed as it is part of the PHP core in most distros (even on Windows or shared hosting). I think there is no "better", having that BC is available on your box, you need to check whether it works for your application or not. The big pro would be the platform compatibility as it is available in most PHP installations

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you so much. I think i'm gonna use bc Math instead.