# Options to load DLL in PHP (7.0) at run time?

Tags: php, postgresql, dll, runtime, dynamic-loading

I'm building small application to collect data. For data collection PHP is used, for data storage PostgreSQL is used. PostgreSQL is included so I have full control over it. The PHP for collection is triggered by external entity and I have no control over PHP interpreter that will run the code.

Is there a way how to load `php_pgsql.dll`? at run-time?
I know it was asked already, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800467/load-dll-at-runtime-in-php), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607686/loading-a-php-extension-at-runtime-results-in-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined) and my best source of information was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685565/how-to-run-php-extensions-at-runtime). If I get it right there is no way if I'm not root of the system (because `dl()` was removed).

I can add PHP to my application the same way I have added PostgreSQL (to have control over PostgreSQL and do not need to ask someone to install, configure, maintain...), BUT my PHP files are triggered by external application so I have no control over used PHP interpreter/environment.

Is there a way to start from PHP code (let's call it `systemPHP`) the same PHP code but in different PHP environment (`myPHP` environment I have control over and where I will have the dll included)?

For example if systemPHP starts `collect.php` the pseudo code of `collect.php` will be:

```
if <this is myPHP> { # How to detect it?
  <execute the data collection code>
}
else {
  <Start collect.php in myPHP transfering all the data to it> # For example if started by apache then also headers, session information etc...
  <Send back result from myPHP via the systemPHP>
}
```

How to achieve this PHP 'tunnel'?

Thanks for any help or hint. I know that best will be root or at least have intelligent admin, however this is not the case :-(

Currently I'm trying workaround by executing database tasks via shell and then getting response back in PHP, but sometimes it works sometimes not and I believe there is a better way of doing this (not to mention speed and resource usage).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using a messaging queue system? Write to the queue, then have your PHP script running that has php_pgsql.dll already loaded, which checks for new messages in the queue and processes them.